# Solve for x,y: $x^2+1=2y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve for integers $x,y$ such that $x^2+1=2y^2$?

I tried factoring as $(x-y)(x+y)=(y-1)(y+1)$ but couldn't continue from here, I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up Pell's equation. This is a common variant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks! I didn't know about this. It is called negative Pell, I found an article on it. (If you make into a comment I will accept, since I don't need this question anymore, or maybe it can be closed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation). This is a variant, the negative Pell equation.